# How to limit the number of "FileUploadBox()" button?

Tags: javascript, html

I was developing up my new web form and I'm putting some files upload boxes.

I already got it and make it work, but I'm struggling with how limit the upload files buttons.

I want to limit to a maximum of five buttons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
    function addFileUploadBox() {
        if (!document.getElementById || !document.createElement)
            return false;

        var uploadArea = document.getElementById("upload-area");

        if (!uploadArea)
            return;

        var newLine = document.createElement("br");
        uploadArea.appendChild(newLine);

        var newUploadBox = document.createElement("input");
        newUploadBox.type = "file";
        newUploadBox.size = "30";

        if (!addFileUploadBox.lastAssignedId)
            addFileUploadBox.lastAssignedId = 100;

        newUploadBox.setAttribute("id", "FileField" + 
        addFileUploadBox.lastAssignedId);

        newUploadBox.setAttribute("name", "FileField" + 
        addFileUploadBox.lastAssignedId);

        uploadArea.appendChild(newUploadBox);

        addFileUploadBox.lastAssignedId++;
    }    
    </script>

    <p id="upload-area">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="30">
    </p>

    <input type="button" value="Attach more files" id="btAdd" class="button1" 
    onclick="addFileUploadBox()">

</body>
</html>
```

Please guys, give me a light of how may I could solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `addFileUploadBox` function, you can check to see if there are already 5 boxes on the page, and prevent it from creating more.

`if(document.querySelectorAll('#upload-area input[type="file"]').length >= 5) return false;`

Comment: Ow my God, I love you! Cheers mate, you helped me so much.
God bless you.

Comment: Solved, Thank you so much!